# Zend Framework - Redirects

Tags: php, zend-framework

Running ZF + xampp on localhost (I'm new to this)..

I have this code:

```
    $url = $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
    ...
    $session->requestURL = $url;
```

& var_dump shows $url=

```
    /kakool/public/admin/catalog/item/update/1
```

But later, in this code:

```
    if (isset($session->requestURL)) {
    $url = $session->requestURL; }
    # again, var_dump shows $url=/kakool/public/admin/catalog/item/update/1
    $this->_redirect($url);
```

It's redirecting to this url:

```
    /kakool/public/kakool/public/admin/catalog/item/update/1
```

Annoying... Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_redirect` method defaults to assuming you're giving it a path relative to the root of the current app - so even if you pass a URL starting with `/`, it'll append the base path to the front of it.

You have two options:

1/ Give it a path relative to the project like it wants:

```
$url = $this->getRequest()->getPathInfo();
# var_dump now shows $url=/admin/catalog/item/update/1
$this->_redirect($url);
```

2/ Pass an extra flag that tells the _redirect not to add the base path:

```
$this->_redirect($url, array('prependBase' => false));
```

Comment: or you could use $request->getPathInfo();

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to replace this :

```
$url = $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
...
$session->requestURL = $url;
```

with this :

```
$url = $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
...
if(!isset($session->requestURL)){
    $session->requestURL = $url;
}
```